# How to add an element in the your index inside a array? ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm doing the game Tic Tac Toe, but i have a problem..

I want to add the element in an array in the position that was passed.

My app.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Square from './Square.js';
import './Square.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      board: Array(9).fill(''),
      currentUser: 'X',
      position: Array(9).fill(''),
    }
  }

  changeUser = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentUser: this.state.currentUser === 'X' ? "O" : "X",
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="game">
        <div id='head'>
          <h5> Tic Tac Toe Jcsouz Games </h5>

        </div>
        <div id="board">
          {this.state.board.map((v, i) => <Square position={this.state.position} value={i} key={i} changeUser={this.changeUser} currentUser={this.state.currentUser}>
            {props => (<span>{props}</span>)}
          </Square>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Square.js (where i do the `push`);

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Square.css';

class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      player: '',
    }
  }

  changePlayer = () => {
    const { changeUser, value, position, currentUser } = this.props;

    position.push(currentUser);

    changeUser();
    
    if (this.state.player === '') {
      this.setState({
        player: this.props.currentUser,
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="square" onClick={this.changePlayer}>
        {this.props.children(this.state.player)}
        {this.props.children(this.state.position)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Square;
```

What needs to happen: Each square has its index (from 0 to 8), I wanted it, for example: If I clicked on the square number 0, it added the value of it in the array in position 0 ['X','','','','','','','',''], or if I clicked on square 4, Position 4 ['','','','X','','','','',''].

I tryed do, but gave error:
[image]

Someone would can help me ? Please..

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: It is the print, it add in the end of the array :(

Comment: Never mutate props passed to you. Pass down a callback from the parent to the child which the child calls, and, have the parent callback call `setState`

Comment: try `.splice(position, 0, player)` instead of pushing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position.push()` method will only add to the array. To affect a certain position of an array you need:

```
this.state = {
 board: Array(9).fill('') 
}

this.state.board[1] = 'X'
```

The last line of code will replace the current value on the 1st position of the board variable with a 'X' character giving you:

```
["", "X", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Hope it helps.

#### UPDATE

My understanding is that the `slice()` method will insert a element into the middle of the array. As a result, it will grow. I think that is not your objective

#### UPDATE

You should always use the `setState()` function to update the state of a component

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a splice function, to put an item into a specific position

so you should do it like

```
position.splice(thePosition, 0, valueToBeInserted);
```

you can read its docs in https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

You're using:

```
position.push(currentUser);
```

this adds the element 'currentUser' to the array. That's not what you want!

You should instead do:

```
position[i] = currentUser;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
position.push(currentUser);
```

to

```
position.splice(value, 1, currentUser);
```

next step: pass a handler down to `Square` that updates the state in `App` instead of mutating the state in `Square`.